# Request for example: Recurrent neural network for predicting next value in a sequence

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, time-series, pybrain

Can anyone give me a practicale example of a recurrent neural network in (pybrain) python in order to predict the next value of a sequence ?
(I've read the pybrain documentation and there is no clear example for it I think.)
I also found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689293/event-sequences-recurrent-neural-networks-pybrain). But I fail to see how it works in a more general case. So therefore I'm asking if anyone here could work out a **clear example of how to predict the next value of a sequence in pybrain, with a recurrent neural network**.

To give an example.

Say for example we have a sequence of numbers in the range [1,7].

```
First run (So first example): 1 2 4 6 2 3 4 5 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 7 1 2 3 5 6

Second run (So second example): 1 2 5 6 2 4 4 5 1 2 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 3 3 6

Third run (So third example): 1 3 5 7 2 4 6 7 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 2 3 7

and so on.
```

Now given for example the start of a new sequence: **1 3 5 7 2 4 6 7 1 3**

what is/are the next value(s)

This question might seem lazy, but I think there lacks a good and decent example of how to do this with pybrain.

---

**Additionally: How can this be done if more than 1 feature is present:**

Example:

Say for example we have several sequences (each sequence having 2 features) in the range [1,7].

```
First run (So first example): feature1: 1 2 4 6 2 3 4 5 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 7 1 2 3 5 6
                              feature2: 1 3 5 7 2 4 6 7 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 2 3 7


Second run (So second example): feature1: 1 2 5 6 2 4 4 5 1 2 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 3 3 6
                                feature2: 1 2 3 7 2 3 4 6 2 3 5 6 7 2 4 7 1 3 3 5 6    

Third run (So third example): feature1: 1 3 5 7 2 4 6 7 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 2 3 7
                              feature2: 1 2 4 6 2 3 4 5 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 7 1 2 3 5 6

and so on.
```

Now given for example the start of a new sequences:

```
                                            feature 1: 1 3 5 7 2 4 6 7 1 3

                                            feature 2: 1 2 3 7 2 3 4 6 2 4
```

what is/are the next value(s)

---

Feel free to use your own example as long it is similar to these examples and has some in depth explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Issam Laradji's worked for me to predict sequence of sequences, except my version of pybrain required a tuple for the UnserpervisedDataSet object:

```
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet,UnsupervisedDataSet
from pybrain.structure import LinearLayer
ds = SupervisedDataSet(21, 21)
ds.addSample(map(int,'1 2 4 6 2 3 4 5 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 7 1 2 3 5 6'.split()),map(int,'1 2 5 6 2 4 4 5 1 2 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 3 3 6'.split()))
ds.addSample(map(int,'1 2 5 6 2 4 4 5 1 2 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 3 3 6'.split()),map(int,'1 3 5 7 2 4 6 7 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 2 3 7'.split()))
net = buildNetwork(21, 20, 21, outclass=LinearLayer,bias=True, recurrent=True)
trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds)
trainer.trainEpochs(100)
ts = UnsupervisedDataSet(21,)
ts.addSample(map(int,'1 3 5 7 2 4 6 7 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 2 3 7'.split()))
[ int(round(i)) for i in net.activateOnDataset(ts)[0]]
```

gives:

*`=>  [1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 1, 4, 6, 1, 2, 2, 3, 6]`*

To predict smaller sequences, just train it up as such, either as sub sequences or as overlapping sequences (overlapping shown here):

```
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet,UnsupervisedDataSet
from pybrain.structure import LinearLayer
ds = SupervisedDataSet(10, 11)
z = map(int,'1 2 4 6 2 3 4 5 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 7 1 2 3 5 6 1 2 5 6 2 4 4 5 1 2 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 3 3 6 1 3 5 7 2 4 6 7 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 2 3 7'.split())
obsLen = 10
predLen = 11
for i in xrange(len(z)):
  if i+(obsLen-1)+predLen < len(z):
    ds.addSample([z[d] for d in range(i,i+obsLen)],[z[d] for d in range(i+1,i+1+predLen)])

net = buildNetwork(10, 20, 11, outclass=LinearLayer,bias=True, recurrent=True)
trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds)
trainer.trainEpochs(100)
ts = UnsupervisedDataSet(10,)
ts.addSample(map(int,'1 3 5 7 2 4 6 7 1 3'.split()))
[ int(round(i)) for i in net.activateOnDataset(ts)[0]]
```

gives:

*`=>  [3, 5, 6, 2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 5, 6]`*

Not too good...

Comment: Your second example seems like a viable answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate "viable" answer?   How do you judge if the output is "ok"?   Based on the original examples?   But there so few examples given.

Answer (score 4):

These steps are meant to perform what you ask for in the first part of the question.

1) Create a supervised dataset that expects a sample and a target in its arguments,

```
 ds = SupervisedDataSet(21, 21)
 #add samples (this can be done automatically)
 ds.addSample(map(int,'1 2 4 6 2 3 4 5 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 7 1 2 3 5 6'.split()),map(int,'1 2 5 6 2 4 4 5 1 2 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 3 3 6'.split()))
 ds.addSample(map(int,'1 2 5 6 2 4 4 5 1 2 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 3 3 6'.split()),map(int,'1 3 5 7 2 4 6 7 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 2 3 7'.split()))
```

A succeeding sample is the target or label `y` of its predecessor `x`. We put the number `21` because each sample has `21` numbers or features.

Please note that for standard notations in the second half of your question it is better to call feature1 and feature2 as sample1 and sample2 for a sequence, and let features denote the numbers in a sample.

2) Create Network, initialize trainer and run for 100 epochs

```
net = buildNetwork(21, 20, 21, outclass=LinearLayer,bias=True, recurrent=True)
trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds)
trainer.trainEpochs(100)
```

Make sure to set the `recurrent` argument as `True`

3) Create the test data

```
ts = UnsupervisedDataSet(21, 21)
#add the sample to be predicted
ts.addSample(map(int,'1 3 5 7 2 4 6 7 1 3 5 6 7 1 4 6 1 2 2 3 7'.split()))
```

We created an unsupervised dataset because of the assumption that we don't have the labels or targets.

4) Predict the test sample using the trained network

```
net.activateOnDataset(ts)
```

This should display the values of the expected `fourth run`.

For the second case when a sequence can have more than sample, instead of creating a supervised dataset, create a sequential one `ds = SequentialDataSet(21,21)`. Then, everytime you get a new sequence, call `ds.newSequence()` and add the samples -that you call features- in that sequence using `ds.addSample()`.

Hope this is clear-cut :)

If you wish to have the full code to save the trouble of importing the libraries, please let me know.

Comment: Hmm you don't seem to answer the question... 

"Now given for example the start of a new sequence: 1 3 5 7 2 4 6 7 1 3 

what is/are the next value(s)"

So what comes after the last 3 in the sequence ?

Comment: Answering your specific question, given just so few examples, has no meaning - anything is possible.   But What @Curious has given is the algorithm of doing it, and if you feed it with large number of sequence - which we are not sure HOW you get the sequence - the accuracies of output will be higher.   Specific answer is not what we are interested.